# Django-CMS default SEO settings

Tags: python, django, seo, settings, django-cms

Based on the [Django CMS documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/configuration.html#cms-seo-fields), by enabling the CMS_SEO_FIELDS,  a fieldset with the SEO settings will appear in the administration page of **every** CMS page. By default, these settings are empty.

Is there a way to have some default settings (description and keyword meta tags) added to every page which will be overwritten if the page provides it's own settings?

Maybe I could use something like this: [Django CMS - check if placeholder is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147720/django-cms-check-if-placeholder-is-empty) but it's not an optimal solution, since I won't be able to translate the default content of the meta tags.

Comment: Please note that in django-cms 3.0 this field has been removed: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1739

Comment: Did you ever find a solid way to do SEO with Django CMS?

Comment: @MadPhysicist did you find anything suitable?

Comment: We use `djangocms-page-meta` to set a few SEO parameters, and then `django-check-seo` to check if current page have correct SEO ([example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/45763865/72882024-2b113b80-3d02-11ea-8507-6cb48f9f34b3.png)). (PSA: I developed django-check-seo)